# nginx reverse proxy static files relative pass

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, redirect

I have simple reverse proxy setup with nginx (which runs in docker container with certbot https://github.com/umputun/nginx-le) as webserver on `example.com` and `192.168.0.220:80` where my app runs. There is config:

```
server {
    listen   443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    charset utf-8;

    ssl_certificate         SSL_CERT;
    ssl_certificate_key     SSL_KEY;
    ssl_trusted_certificate SSL_CHAIN_CERT;

    location /smarthome/ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.220:80/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Origin '';
    }
}
```

And web page with static resources defined like this `<script src="/js/home.js"></script>`

Problem is when I access `example.com/smarthome` it doesn't load my static resouces. In console:

```
https://example.com/js/home.js/smarthome/smarthome/smarthome/smarthome/smarthome/smarthome/smarthome/smarthome/smarthome/smarthome/smarthome/smarthome/smarthome/smarthome/smarthome/smarthome/smarthome/smarthome/smarthome/smarthome net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

But expected to get statis resouces form `https://example.com/smarthome/js/home.js` but it seems to get in redirect loop.

I might miss something very simple, but cannot find solution while frustration comes over.
Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Use `curl` or restart your browser to be sure the redirection cycle wasn't cached by the browser. The nginx configuration you posted has no infinite loop, maybe the other server is sending redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Nginx configuration, you must define the root location. Otherwise, it always redirects the loop.

You can make the configuration file like this:

```
server {
    listen   443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    charset utf-8;

    ssl_certificate         SSL_CERT;
    ssl_certificate_key     SSL_KEY;
    ssl_trusted_certificate SSL_CHAIN_CERT;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.220:80;
    }

    location /smarthome/ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.220:80/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Origin '';
    }
}
```